# How to authenticate to webservice using KSOAP Android library

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am in the middle of understanding android programming in particular and I just want to create a simple POC on how to call SOAP based web service from an android app.

Based on my readings, I can used this library [KSOAP2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Links)

I haven't done serious coding yet but I just would like to know how to implement authentication using this library.

In the examples that I have seen on the net, almost all of them has no authentication mechanism.  If my web service requires authentication such as a userid/password then how can I pass it along using this library.

Just would like a lead to start on. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out the ksoap library?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the second part of your questions my webservice is in vb.net and requires a username and password so i have a webmethod that handles that. This is the android side that handles it... There is also an adapter but Ill let you get that part.

```
public Account getAccountFromWebservice() {

    SOAP_ACTION = "getAccount";
    METHOD_NAME = "getAccount";

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(Data.NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    String username = "name";
    String password = "something";



    PropertyInfo username = new PropertyInfo();
    username .setName("username ");
    username .setValue(username);
    Request.addProperty(username );



    PropertyInfo password = new PropertyInfo();
    password.setName("password ");
    password.setValue(password );
    Request.addProperty(password );

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE HttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Data.URL);

    try {
        HttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            account.setProperty(i, response.getProperty(i).toString());

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return account;

}
```

and here is a part of the .net webervice method

```
        public Accounts[] getAccounts(String username, String password)
    {
        strSQL = "dbo.danceworks_getAccounts";
        SqlParameter[] sp = new SqlParameter[2];
        sp[0] = new SqlParameter("@username", username);
        sp[1] = new SqlParameter("@password", password);



        DatabaseCore dc = new DatabaseCore();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = dc.ExecSPReturnDS(strSQL, sp);

        Accounts[] account= new Accounts[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            account[i] = new Accounts();
            Accounts[i].add the various fields for an account object
        }

        return Classes;
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi... From which class you got Account, from Ksoap2? But there is no class named Account from Ksoap2

Comment: It is an class I made. in my webservice I have an account class with data fields such as account ID's or students. So on the Android side I made an account class and I did fefined out all the variables that I had in my account class in the web service side